# LEGO twin-engine airplane (black/yellow/grey) set identification please

Tags: technic, set-identification, vehicle

Bought this airplane "as is" at a flea market. Pieces missing. I want to repair it. Does anyone here have the LEGO set number or know where I can find the instructions ? I suspect that it is several years old (1980s ? 1990s ?).
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is set 8425 (quite a nice set imho) and the instructions are downloadable from lego themselves:
https://www.lego.com/biassets/bi/4101173.pdf
The set is from 1996